# Updating event is not fire in Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have created a function for updating a loan amount with respect to EMI. In this function, the loan amount updates successfully during creation and deletion of EMI, but not on update of EMI.

EMI Model

```
    <?php namespace App;

       use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

      class Emi extends Model {

    //
    protected  $table = 'emi';

    protected $fillable = ['loan_id', 'amount', 'description', 'date'];



    public function loan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Loan');
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function($emi){
            $loan=\App\Loan::find($emi->loan_id);
            $loan->paid -= $emi->amount;
            $loan->balance += $emi->amount;
            $loan->save();
        });

        static::saved(function($emi){
            $loan=\App\Loan::find($emi->loan_id);

            $loan->paid += $emi->amount;
            $loan->balance -= $emi->amount;
            $loan->save();
        });

        static::updating(function($emi){

            $loan=\App\Loan::find($emi->loan_id);

            $loan->paid -= $emi->amount;
            $loan->balance += $emi->amount;
            return $loan->save();
        });


    }
  }
```

Emi Controller

```
      <?php

       namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

       use Illuminate\Http\Request as Request;

        use App\Http\Requests;
       use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
      use Validator;
      use Response;

     use App\Account;
     use App\Loan;
     use App\Emi;

     class EmiController extends Controller
     { 

          /**
 * New data validation
 * @param array $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data,[
        'loan_id'     =>'required|numeric',
        'amount'      =>'required|numeric|max:999999999999999999',
        'description' =>'required|alpha_text|max:250',
        'date'        =>'required|date',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the Emi resource.
 * If loan id is not given, then returns all Emi resource.
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
 */

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $loan_id = $request->get('loan_id');

    //All Emi recipets for loan
    if($loan_id !==NULL)
        return Loan::find($loan_id)->emi;
    else
        return Emi::with('loan')->get();
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json( $validator->errors()
            ,400);
    }

    $emi = new Emi($request->all());

    //TODO Loan balance update

    if($emi->save()){
        return $emi;
    }

    return Response::json( ['error' => 'Server is down']
        ,500);
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
    return Emi::find($id);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 * @param $id
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function update($id,Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json($validator->errors()
            ,400);
    }

    //TODO Update loan  balance
    $emi = Emi::find($id);
    //$emi->fill($request->all());

    if($emi->update($request->all())){
        return $emi;
    }

    return Response::json( ['error' => 'Server is down']
        ,500);
}


/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //TODO delete emi balance change in loan
    if(Emi::destroy($id))
        return Response::json(array('msg'=>'Emi deleted'));
    else
        return Response::json(array('error'=>'Records not found'),400);
   }
 }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced some issues with Model's event system. Sometimes it just does not work, and also it has the disadvantage that you can't put all your dependent DB operations inside a transaction.

Althout a bit hacky, I think the most reliable way of inserting/updating/deleting related Models (if you want to ensure DB relational integrity) is by extending the save() and delete() methods, like this:

```
class Model extends Eloquent {

    $hasCustomInsert = false;
    $hasCustomUpdate = false;
    $hasCustomDelete = false;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        foreach(get_class_methods($this) as $method) {
            if (in_array($method,['preInsert','postInsert'])) $this->hasCustomInsert = true;
            if (in_array($method,['preEdit','postEdit'])) $this->hasCustomUpdate = true;
            if (in_array($method,['preDelete','postDelete'])) $this->hasCustomDelete = true;
        }
    }

    public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        //Custom Insert
        if (!$this->exists && $this->hasCustomInsert) {
            return DB::transaction(function() use($options) {

                $this->preInsert();
                $saved = parent::save($options);
                $this->postInsert();

                return $saved;
            });
        }

        //Custom Update
        if ($this->exists && $this->hasCustomUpdate) {
            return DB::transaction(function() use($options) {

                $this->preEdit();
                $saved = parent::save($options);
                $this->postEdit();

                return $saved;
            });
        }

        return parent::save($options);
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        //Custom Delete
        if ($this->exists && $this->hasCustomDelete) {
            return DB::transaction(function() {

                $this->preDelete();
                $deleted = parent::delete();
                $this->postDelete();

                return $deleted;
            });
        }

        return parent::delete();
    }

}
```

Use this on a custom base Model class, that extends Eloquent. All your models should then extend from your base class, instead of extending Eloquent directly.

Then, you can add whatever you want in your preInsert(), postInsert(), preEdit(), postEdit(), preDelete() and postDelete() methods of your child Models. If the child Model doesn't implement those methods, save() and delete() will just call Eloquent's methods like always.